# mongo config server with mongo cluster

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo cluster of 1 Main mongo, with 3 shards en 3 config servers.
Each shard have a primary mongo database, a secundairy mongo database and an arbiter mongo database.

So in total I have 13 servers with mongo on it.

Al the mongo database are running on version 2.6

What I want is to upgrade all the databases to mongo 3.2.
Because this is a production database I want to do this in steps.

Question 1:
   Is this possible, without downtime?

Question 2: So can I, for example, upgrade the config servers with from 2.6 to 3.2, without stopping the database cluster.

Question 3:  Can a mongo 3.2 secundairy server running along a mongo 2.6 primairy server?

Question 4:  Can a shard running on mongo 2.6 runing along with a shard running on mongo 3.2 shard?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: Yes. It's called Rolling Maintenance. I recommend to read this guide [Your Ultimate Guide to rolling upgrades](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/your-ultimate-guide-to-rolling-upgrades) and to practice the steps in a safe environment before doing it on production.

Basic procedure for all nodes:

1. shutdown down node
2. replace  binaries
3. (optional) restart node without --replSet and on different port
4. (optional) do maintenance work in server
5. restart node with --replSet and on original port

Q2-5: are preconditions for 1, so, all: yes.

Comment: But when I only replace the binaries, than the storage engine is still MMAPv1.  
Is it correct then when I want to switch to storage engine WiredTiger, I have to export and then import the data?

Comment: Yes, the files that contain the data are completely different.But even this can be done node by node. I.e. replace a secondary with an empty WT secondary and perform inital sync. see here https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/change-replica-set-wiredtiger/